# Highcharts panning chart on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, highcharts, panning

I'd like to build a chart with panning, like this one http://jsfiddle.net/6ccc08yg/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        panning: true,
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1#', '2#', '3#', '4#', '5#', '6#', '7#', '8#', '9#', '10#', '11#', '12#', '13#', '14#', '15#', '16#', '17#', '18#', '19#', '20#', '21#', '22#', '23#', '24#', '25#', '26#', '27#', '28#', '29#', '30#', '31#', '32#', '33#', '34#', '35#', '36#', '37#', '38#', '39#', '40#', '41#', '42#', '43#', '44#', '45#', '46#', '47#', '48#', '49#', '50#', '51#', '52#', '53#', '54#', '55#', '56#', '57#', '58#', '59#', '60#', '61#', '62#', '63#', '64#', '65#', '66#', '67#', '68#', '69#', '70#', '71#', '72#', '73#', '74#', '75#', '76#', '77#', '78#', '79#', '80#', '81#', '82#', '83#', '84#', '85#', '86#', '87#', '88#'],
        min: 0,
        max:18

    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 10
    },
    series: [{
        data: [0, 0, 8, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}]
    });
});
```

Unfortunately it is not working on mobile devices, and I need to show it on mobile devices, in particular within a Ionic app.

I also tried adding followTouchMove=false, but this didn't change anything.
I already tried also adding pinchType='x' as suggested online, but neither this worked.

How can I get a panning chart that works on mobile devices?

Thanks,
Sabrina

Comment: There is the open ticket related to panning on mobile. See [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2903) Following the answer if you set pinchType to 'x', you should be able to pan the chart with two fingers. http://jsfiddle.net/9ffup38z/3/

Comment: I already tried that, but unfortunateley it isn't working.